# PreferenceActivity getSupportLoaderManager()

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, preferenceactivity

I use ActionBarSherlock in my app.

What I would like to do is to use `CursorLoader` in `PreferenceActivity`. It's possible, but as far as I can see, only on API level >= 11.

I thought that maybe `SherlockPreferenceActivity` would solve it, but it doesn't have `getSupportFragmentManager()` either. (tagging it as `actionbarsherlock` because, maybe I missed something)

Is there any way to use standard preference activity with loader and support older platforms or should I just build a custom preference screen?

Comment: Just chiming that ABS' `SherlockPreferenceActivity` means that it provides Sherlock APIs (the action bar) on top of a normal `PreferenceActivity`. This is why only `SherlockFragmentActivity` has this functionality pre-API 11.

Comment: Please, make this like an answer